# Dosbox fullscreen mode shows a black screen

Tags: fullscreen, dosbox

I'm having a bit of a problem with dosbox when it's on fullscreen mode. It's all black. I'm running a very old commercial app that requires alotta tinkering to add a Greek keyboard and other tricks so I am not surprised this doesn't show properly.
The app runs fine on windowed mode.

- [`dosbox.conf`](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25030950/)
- My OS version is Ubuntu 17.04.

Comment: One question at a time please :)

Comment: hehe sorry ^^ I got greedy

Comment: Please [edit] your question to focus on the one question you are realy interested in.

Comment: OK, Just did it. By the way, while I didn't manage to find a solution to this problem, changing the resolution so that it was a larger screen did help. I am putting this here so that maybe someone in the future might benefit from it. I went back to the stable version of ubuntu (16.04) and fullscreen works.

Comment: Hmm if you can't verify the answer I'm tempted to leave closed! I guess I'll have to see if I can reproduce the problem myself

Answer (score 1):

Try tinkering with different output configurations.

```
output: What video system to use for output.
#                   Possible values: surface, overlay, opengl, openglnb.
```

I have usually had pretty good luck with opengl.

I am not sure what you mean by "to have dosbox automatically run with some commands".  I'm assuming you mean the autoexec feature found at the bottom of the conf file?

```
[autoexec]
# Lines in this section will be run at startup.
# You can put your MOUNT lines here.
```

You can create configuration files for each game by copying and renaming the original config file.  Then create a script to run you game.  Making use of command

```
dosbox -conf /path/to/gameSpecificConfigFile
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the autoexec advice works perfectly! Now, I tried adding all the different types of output and nothing works.  I'll keep trying :)

Comment: Might want to try different full-screen resolutions in the config file.  
e.g. (fullresolution=1360x768).   instead of (fullresolution=original).  Use whatever your systems resolution is or slightly less.